# Complex Numbers with Integer Coefficient

Tags: complex-numbers

I have recently learnt about complex numbers, but there still has been a question in my head:

Is there a number $k$, where $k$ is in the form of $bi$ (where $b$ is an integer), such that when $n$ is a positive integer and $r$ is a negative integer, we have
$$n^k=r?$$

Note: I've changed the question, so some comments may not make sense.

Comment: Complex numbers do that too.

Comment: **Hint:** $$e^{i\pi}=-1.$$

Comment: Thanks, I forgot Euler's identity

Comment: Okay, I changed the question, thank you for helping!

Comment: See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm

Comment: @CheeseCake good point.  I deleted my comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is no. In fact, there are no integers $n > 1, b \ne 0$ for $n^{ib}$ to be real.

If that happens,

$$\Im n^{ib} = \Im e^{ib\log n} = \sin(b\log n) = 0$$
implies we can find an integer $N \ne 0$ so that

$$\log(n)b = N\pi\quad\implies\quad(e^\pi)^N = n^b\quad\implies\quad e^\pi \text{ is algebraic}.$$

This contradicts with the fact that the [Gelfond's constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond%27s_constant)  $e^{\pi}$ is [transcendental](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_number).